# How to install github CLI inside jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, github-cli

am trying to install github cli in the jenkins pipeline using this commands from github CLI docs :

```
type -p curl >/dev/null || sudo apt install curl -y
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& sudo chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null \
&& sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install gh -y
```

But it gives me this error :

```
dd: can't open '/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg': No such file or directory
curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```